# Change the "clicked" current button background

Tags: jquery, vue.js, vuejs2

When I click a button in a list of buttons, all the buttons in the `for`-loop change their backgrounds. I already added a method on `click`, and applied CSS to the button, but I don't know how to change the background color of only the clicked button.

*App.vue:*

```html
<template>
  <div id="app">
    <!-- <button v-on:click="counter += 1">Add 1</button> -->
    <button
      class="button variation colors"
      v-for="(p,index) in varbutss"
      :key="index"
      :id="p.items_id"
      :value="p.color"
      @click="colorclick(p.items_id,p.color)"
    >{{p.color}}</button>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import $ from "jquery";
export default {
  name: "App",
  methods: {
    colorclick: function(e,color) {
      console.log(e);

      $(".colors").css("background-color", color);
    }
  },
  data() {
    return {
      varbutss: [
        {
          items_id: 1,
          color: "red"
        },
        {
          items_id: 2,
          color: "blue"
        }
      ]
    };
  }
};
</script>

<style>
#app {
  font-family: "Avenir", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
  -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
  -moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale;
  text-align: center;
  color: #2c3e50;
  margin-top: 60px;
}
</style>
```

https://codesandbox.io/s/optimistic-dijkstra-st34h?file=/src/App.vue

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is in this line:

```js
$(".colors").css("background-color", color);
```

The `$(".colors")` code finds all elements with the classname of `colors`. Since each button is assigned the `colors` class, all buttons are returned, which causes all buttons to have the same color.

Your `click`-handler passes the button ID as the first argument, so you could use that in your query to limit the scope of color changes to that button. That is, change the selector to be `#BUTTONID.colors`:

```js
colorclick: function(e, color) {
  $(`#${e}.colors`).css("background-color", color);
}
```

[demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/recursing-aryabhata-pm76k?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&module=%2Fsrc%2FApp.vue&theme=dark)

---

However, DOM manipulation (with jQuery) should be avoided because those changes will be overwritten if Vue rerenders the component. There's typically a way to rewrite your code without manipulating the DOM. For example, you could apply a `class` based on a variable that is set by your `click`-handler.